How to transpose 'ExprMulElement' object in mosek Fusion API
I am trying to transpose an expression in fusion.
According to fusion API's document I tried to transpose the Expression by Expr.transpose() method. However, It is not working for "ExprMulElement".
import mosek.fusion as *

# Create a model
M = Model()

# Example dimensions
N, C = 4, 3

# Define a variable (N x C matrix)
X = M.variable([N, C])

A = np.random.rand(N, C)

Y = Expr.mulElm(A, X)

# Transpose the matrix (C x N)
Y_transpose = Y.transpose()


The error is this.
AttributeError: 'ExprMulElement' object has no attribute 'transpose'
How can I transpose an "ExprMulElement" object?

Expr.transpose(Y) or, if you are using Mosek 10.2 and the pythonic syntax, then simply Y.T. See https://docs.mosek.com/latest/pythonfusion/expr.html#expr.transpose for details
